# Streaming Json data to ASP.NET ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-apicontroller

I am trying to write an `ApiController` that streams JSON data in the response. It goes something like this;

```cs
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    IDocumentWriter _writer;

    public MyController(IDocumentWriter writer)
    {
        _writer = writer;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            response.Content = new StreamContent(stream);
            await _writer.WriteAsync(stream);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
            response.Content.Headers.ContentLength = stream.Length;
        }

        return response;
    }
}
```

The `IDocumentWriter` accepts a stream and writes the JSON data to it. A call to `Get` fails with a `System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException`, which I don't understand because I am awaiting the `WriteAsync`. Surely it finishes writing before returning? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The example you're using isn't really taking advantage of streaming because a `MemoryStream` represents a fixed-size buffer in-memory - it's no better than using `ByteArrayContent`. You should write directly to the `HttpContext.Response` output stream.

Comment: Please post the full stack-trace of the `TaskCanceledException`, including the `[Async]` part at the very bottom, and any `InnerException` objects (and their corresponding full stack-traces)

Comment: @Dai you are absolutely right. That is the solution. I just didn't know how to write directly to the output stream using `StreamContent` because that takes a stream, doesn't expose one. Using `PushStreamContent` fixes this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out thanks to [this post](https://gist.github.com/rvhuang/f51b600a82e2517aabbe76bf3917ea00). Turns out I was over complicating things. Here is the final solution;

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Get()
{
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);

    response.Content = new PushStreamContent(async (stream, content, context) =>
    {
        await _writer.WriteAsync(stream);
        stream.Close();
    }, "application/json");

    return response;
}
```